# How to join-query without sqlalchemy ORM relationships

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have struggled so bad from this. I came from php/mysql in which a query like the following is easily executed:

```
SELECT Work_center, ... , MRPW, WCC.Total_Cost FROM tracking LEFT JOIN WCC ON WCC.Well_Type_Code = tracking.PDO_Well_Type
```

But now with python, postgresql and sqlalchemy, it is giving me this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "wcc" does not exist
LINE 1: ...uit, MRPW, WCC.Total_Cost FROM tracking LEFT JOIN WCC ON WCC...
```

It asks me for relationships and relationships ask me for foreign keys but there aren't foreign keys here. I do not want to link the two tables. Although I tried to do it, but it gives me hard time because the two tables' data come from csv file uploads. How can I query with joins without relations and foreign keys?
knowing that I spent hours searching and trying and does not seem to work!

```
class WCC(Base):
    __tablename__ = "WCC"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 

    id =                  Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    Well_Type_Code =      Column(String, index=True)
    Well_Type_Code_year = Column(String, index=True, unique=True)
    Year =                Column(Integer)
    Total_Cost =          Column(Float)
    #wells = relationship("tracking", back_populates="WCC",foreign_keys=[Well_Type_Code], primaryjoin="tracking.PDO_Well_Type == WCC.Well_Type_Code")


class tracking(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tracking"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 

    id =                  Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    Work_center =         Column(String)
    Operation_Short =     Column(String)
    Oper_Act =            Column(String)
    Opr_System_status =   Column(String)
    Earl_start_date =     Column(DateTime)
    EarliestEndDate =     Column(DateTime)
    Station_Code =        Column(String)
    Normal_duration =     Column(Float)
    Norm_duratn_un=       Column(String)
    Well_Name=            Column(String)
    Field =               Column(String)
    Responsible_asset =   Column(String)
    Well_ID =             Column(Integer, unique=True, index=True)
    Well_Location=        Column(String)
    Well_Function=        Column(String)
    Well_Category=        Column(String)
    PCAP_Category=        Column(String)
    Move_days=            Column(Float)
    PDO_Well_Type=        Column(String)

    pick_date =           Column(DateTime)
    pick_date_spud =      Column(DateTime)
    PI_date =             Column(DateTime)
    PI_date_spud =        Column(DateTime)
    location =            Column(Float)
    location_date =       Column(DateTime)
    location_date_spud =  Column(DateTime)
    HUA_date =            Column(DateTime)
    HUA_date_spud =       Column(DateTime)
    WPT_final_date =      Column(DateTime)
    WPT_final_date_spud = Column(DateTime)
    WPT_highlights      = Column(String)
    expected_comm_date  = Column(DateTime)
    commissioning_date  = Column(DateTime)
    EWS_date  =           Column(DateTime)
    cond_conduit=         Column(Text)
    gas_conduit=          Column(Text)
    MRPW=                 Column(Text)
    #cost = relationship("WCC", back_populates="tracking",primaryjoin="tracking.PDO_Well_Type == WCC.Well_Type_Code")
```

Comment: Can you please include your query which is giving you that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres object names are case sensitive when double quoted, and you must ALWAYS double quote them. It looks as though the table is double quoted when created but not when referenced in the query:

```
class WCC(Base):
    __tablename__ = "WCC"

but 
 LEFT JOIN WCC ON
```

Table name "WCC" is not the same as WCC. Try removing the double quotes from where table is created. If that is not possible due to your ORM then double quote on the query itself. But keep in mind you will have to double quote on **every reference**. Avoid double quotes if at all possible, any perceived benefit is just not worth the trouble.

Comment: I had to double quote all table/column names that has capital letters.